# HTML form submission cuts off symbols after space in the values

Tags: python, html, forms, flask, space

I have a Flask web app where I take entry from a form. It has two lists:

```html
<div class="form-row">
  <div class="form-group col-md-6">
    <label for="selected_domain" class="col-form-label">Select domain where service belongs</label>
    <select id="selected_domain" name="selected_domain" class="form-control">
      <option>Choose</option>
      {%for x in domain%}
      <option value="{{x}}">{{x}}</option>
      {%endfor%}
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-6">
    <label for="selected_platform" class="col-form-label">Select platform exposing the service</label>
    <select name="selected_platform" id="selected_platform" class="form-control">
      <option>Choose</option>
      {%for x in platform%}
      <option value={{x}}>{{x}}</option>
      {%endfor%}
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am populating the lists via similar python methods (from graph):

```
def listdomains():
    with driver.session() as session:
        tx=session.begin_transaction()
        statement=("MATCH (d:domain) RETURN d.name ORDER BY d.name")
        statementResult=tx.run(statement).value()
        tx.close()
        session.close()
    return statementResult

def listAllplatforms():
    with driver.session() as session:
        tx=session.begin_transaction()
        statement=("MATCH (p:platform) RETURN p.name ORDER BY p.name")
        statementResult=tx.run(statement).value()
        tx.close()
        session.close()
    return statementResult
```

In the form I get all values properly displayed. Only after submission, I get problems with the value coming back for the Platforms, it cuts off all symbols after the space, if it has space in the value. Please note that the Domains list returns proper value, despite being defined in same way. So, for values "Example Domain 1" and "Example Platform 1" my variables test in python :

```
print(platform)
print("Platform is string",isinstance(platform,str))
print(domain)
print("Domain is string",isinstance(domain,str))
```

returns this:

Console output

[image]

What could be the problem?

Comment: Missing quotes around value `<option value={{x}}>{{x}}</option>`

Comment: Voting to close the question since _It's caused by a typo or problem that can no longer be reproduced. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a way less likely to help future readers._

Answer (score 0):

The answer was in comments - I just want to put it here so next person (as me - flask noob) could understand what's wrong. So you have tO chcnge in your template this part

```
<option value={{x}}>{{x}}</option>
```

to

```
<option value="{{x}}">"{{x}}"</option>
```

The cause of this problem is shown in “View Page Source" of your browser. There you can see

```
<option value=TEXT WITHOUT QUIOOTES>{{x}}</option>
```

But it should look like that:

```
<option value="TEXT WITHOUT QUIOOTES">"{{x}}"</option>
```